# How do I set root path to '/' without controller and action in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, comfortable-mexican-sofa

In my **routes.rb** I want to set the root_path to '/' without specifying any controller or action. Is that possible?

I tried `root to: '/'` but it's complaining, that no controller or action is specified.

**Updated Info:**

I'm using the [comfortable-mexican-sofa](https://github.com/glebm/comfortable-mexican-sofa) CMS, and my root_path should go to the cms root path.

At the moment I'm just using `redirect_to '/'` in my controllers and this is working, but I thought it would be nicer to use `root_path`.

Comment: where do you want root to point, then?

Comment: I think you're confused here. When you do: `root to: 'home#index'` that means you define: `localhost:3000` to call: "home#index" action. Are you trying to do something else? maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
root :to => "cms/content#show"
```

From the docs: https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/wiki/Pages

> The first page you create is the homepage, and therefore you cannot specify a slug. By default, you should be able to access the homepage without specifying your root route. However, if you or a gem you are using need access to the root_path helper, specify `root :to => "cms/content#show"` in your routes.

Answer (score 4):

Further to the accepted answer, the `routes` of Rails is all about creating the paths for your application

According to the [ActionDispatch::Routing middleware](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html) documentation:

> The routing module provides URL rewriting in native Ruby. It's a way to
>   redirect incoming requests to controllers and actions. This replaces
>   mod_rewrite rules. Best of all, Rails' Routing works with any web
>   server. Routes are defined in config/routes.rb

This means the job of `routes.rb` is to take the inbound request (`/`, `/posts`, etc) & redirect to ruby-centric code. Ruby doesn't know what `/` is -- it *has* to have a `controller` / `action` combo

That's why you'd need something like:

```
#config/routes.rb
root to: "controller#action"
```